# jQuery get parent sibling for this element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I cant figure out how to write this.

See my mark up structure, which is repeated multiple times on a page.

```
<div class="module">    
    <div class="archive-info">
        <span class="archive-meta">
            open
        </span>                         
    </div>
    <div class="archive-meta-slide">
    </div>                              
</div>
```

As you can see inside my mark-up, I have a `<span>` which is my `$metaButton` - when this is clicked, it runs the animation on the `div.archive-meta-slide` - this is simple enough, but I'm trying to run the animation only on the current `div.module` it animates all the divs with the class `"archive-meta-slide"`, and I'm really struggling to animate only the current `div.archive-meta-slide` using `this`

It would be easy if the `div.archive-meta-slide` was inside the parent div of `$metaButton`, but because it's outside this parent div, I can't get the traversing right.

See my script

```
var $metaButton = $("span.archive-meta"),
    $metaSlide = $(".archive-meta-slide");

$metaButton.toggle(
function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(".archive-meta-slide").animate({ height: "0" }, 300);
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(".archive-meta-slide").html("close");
},
function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(".archive-meta-slide").animate({ height: "43px" }, 300);
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(".archive-meta-slide").html("open");
});
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find(".archive-meta-slide")
```

This is *really* close. This actually says "find elements with the class `archive-meta-slide` that are descendants of siblings of this element's parent". You want to say "find elements with the class `archive-meta-slide` that *are* siblings of this element's parent".  For that, use a selector on the `siblings` call:

```
$(this).parent().siblings(".archive-meta-slide")
```

Note that, if the markup is always this structure, you could even do `$(this).parent().next()`.

See the jQuery API:

- [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings)
- [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find)
- [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next)

Answer (score 10):

Use `$(this).closest(".module")` to find the parent module from where the click happens.

You also probably want to use a completion function to change the text after you do the animation.

The nice thing about `.closest()` is that it just looks up the parent chain as far as necessary until it finds an object with the right class.  This is much less fragile than using a specific number of `.parent()` references if someone else changes your HTML design a little bit (adds another div or span or something like that in the parent chain).

```
var $metaButton = $("span.archive-meta");

$metaButton.toggle(
    function() {
        var $slide = $(this).closest(".module").find(".archive-meta-slide");
        $slide.animate({ height: "0" }, 300, function() {
            $slide.html("close");
        });
    },
    function() {
        var $slide = $(this).closest(".module").find(".archive-meta-slide");
        $slide.animate({ height: "43px" }, 300, function() {
            $slide.html("open");
        });
    },
});
```

You could also DRY it up a bit and make a common function:

```
function metaToggleCommon(obj, height, text) {
    var $slide = $(obj).closest(".module").find(".archive-meta-slide");
    $slide.animate({ height: height}, 300, function() {
        $slide.html(text);
    });
}

var $metaButton = $("span.archive-meta");
$metaButton.toggle(
    function() {metaToggleCommon(this, "0", "close")}, 
    function() {metaToggleCommon(this, "43px", "open")}
);
```

Comment: the use of `closest()` is more robust, as jfriend00 has explained.

Answer (score 4):

You’re looking for…

```
$(this).parent().next('.archive-meta-slide')
```

If the structure of #module changes, this might be more robust:

```
$(this).closest('#module').children('.archive-meta-slide')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
jQuery(this).closest('.prev-class-name').find('.classname').first()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(this).parent().parent().children('.archive-meta-slide')
```

This is as good as searching children of top module div

> $(this).parent().parent()

will be your top

```
<div class="module">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) which will let you go back until you reach the parent with the specified selector.

```
$(this).closest(".module")
```