# selecting a specific class with .parents()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can you pass in a class to the jQuery method `parents()`?

I need to check for a menu item match to a data attribute and if there is change the color of a header/link.

[How to find a parent with a known class in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333426/how-to-find-a-parent-with-a-known-class-in-jquery)

Relevant answer:

> Pass a selector to the jQuery parents function:
>
> d.parents('.a').attr('id')

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

The sample code from docs:

```
<script>
function showParents() {
  $( "div" ).css( "border-color", "white" );
  var len = $( "span.selected" )
    .parents( "div" )
      .css( "border", "2px red solid" )
      .length;
  $( "b" ).text( "Unique div parents: " + len );
}
$( "span" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "selected" );
  showParents();
});
</script>
```

This led me to belive that you can pass in a class to that method but that I guess is not the case.

My code:

```js
$(function() {
var tagName = $("#content").data("item")
  $(".sub-menu a").each(function() {
    var menuItem = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (menuItem == tagName) {
      $(this).parents(".big-link").addClass("red");
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" data-item="most important"></div>

<div id="menu">
  <a class="big-link" href="#">This Link should be RED</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Most Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="big-link" href="#">This Link should be untouched</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The expectation is that the first link above the first list should be red, because the content of a menu item and the data attribute match.

In the same above attached answer it says to use `.closest()`

```js
$(function() {
var tagName = $("#content").data("item")
  $(".sub-menu a").each(function() {
    var menuItem = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (menuItem == tagName) {
      $(this).closest(".big-link").addClass("red");
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" data-item="most important"></div>

<div id="menu">
  <a class="big-link" href="#">This Link should be RED</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Most Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="big-link" href="#">This Link should be untouched</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But that doesn't work either. Can you pass a class name into the `.parents()` function? Or is there another function I should use for this?

Comment: Issue is the link is not a parent.... it is a sibling of a parent.

Comment: Both the `closest` and `parents` functions go up the tree structure of the DOM. There are no elements, going from a link within an `li`, that have the class `big-link`. You'll have to go to the `sub-menu` parent, then use `prev` to get to the previous sibling. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8591887/215552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are not looking for a parent, you are looking for an "uncle" It is a sibling of the parent. So find the closest sub-menu and than find the previous sibling.

```js
$(function() {
var tagName = $("#content").data("item")
  $(".sub-menu a").each(function() {
    var menuItem = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (menuItem == tagName) {
      $(this).closest(".sub-menu").prev(".big-link").addClass("red");
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" data-item="most important"></div>

<div id="menu">
  <a class="big-link" href="#">This Link should be RED</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Most Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="big-link" href="#">This Link should be untouched</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Not Important</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```